# How can I deserialize an object from an XML returned from a nusoap service?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization, nusoap

I'm trying to deserialize an object from an Xml which is returned from a NuSoap-Service.
I received the Service with a WSDL-File and tried to implement it into my project. The problem is that the WSDL-File seems to broken. 
I have access to the webservice over SoapUI.I can also do my requests handfilled into an XML-form successfully. In return to a request I get an Xml back from the service.

I already made the classes for some of the requests. I can serialize and post them successfully over and get my Xml-response. Now my actual problem starts. I would like to deserialize this response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="urn:LicenseManagement">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
       <ns1:GetErrorCodesResponse xmlns:ns1="urn:LicenseManagement">
        <RETURN xsi:type="tns:ReturnGetErrorCodes">
          <RC xsi:type="xsd:int">0</RC>
          <DATA xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType=":[55]">
           <item xsi:type="xsd:string">OK</item>
           <item xsi:type="xsd:string">database unavailable</item>
           <item xsi:type="xsd:string">...</item>
          </DATA>
        </RETURN>
       </ns1:GetErrorCodesResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I started with the implementation of the classes for one of the responses.
I could manage to deserialize the Envelope, Body, GetErrorResponse part of this XML. When I reach the RETURN part I get a null.

I know I could use DataSet for my Problem, but that would require a MappingProfile for each response.

```cs
try
{
   //
   GetErrorCodesRequestModel request = new GetErrorCodesRequestModel()
   {
     Username = "xxx" ,
     Password = "zzZzZ"
   };
   var res = XmlExtension.SerializeToString(request);

   XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = CreateSoapEnvelope(res);

   HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(command , "POST");
   InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(soapEnvelopeXml , webRequest);

   IAsyncResult asyncResult = webRequest.BeginGetResponse(null , null);
   asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

   string soapResponse = string.Empty;
   using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
   using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
   {
      soapResponse = rd.ReadToEnd();
   }

// this is the part where I have to deserialize the soapResponse

   var deserialized = XmlExtension.Deserialize<Envelope>(soapResponse);

// deserialized contains information til RETURN
// important information missing
```

My classes look like this atm.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "RC")]
public class RC
{
   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type" , Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
   public string Type { get; set; }
   [XmlText]
   public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "item")]
public class Item
{
   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type" , Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
   public string Type { get; set; }
   [XmlText]
   public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "DATA")]
public class DATA
{
   [XmlElement(ElementName = "item")]
   public Item[] Item { get; set; }
   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type" , Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
   public string Type { get; set; }
   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "arrayType" , Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/")]
   public string ArrayType { get; set; }
}

[XmlType(AnonymousType = true , IncludeInSchema = true)]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "RETURN", Namespace = "tns:ReturnGetErrorCodes" , IsNullable = false)]
public class RETURN
{
   [XmlElement(ElementName = "RC")]
   public RC RC { get; set; }
   [XmlElement(ElementName = "DATA")]
   public DATA DATA { get; set; }
   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type" , Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
   public string Type { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "GetErrorCodesResponse" , Namespace = "urn:LicenseManagement")]
public class GetErrorCodesResponse
{
   [XmlElement(ElementName = "RETURN")]
   public RETURN RETURN { get; set; }
   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ns1" , Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
   public string Ns1 { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body" , Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class Body
{
   [XmlElement(ElementName = "GetErrorCodesResponse" , Namespace = "urn:LicenseManagement")]
   public GetErrorCodesResponse GetErrorCodesResponse { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope" , Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class Envelope
{
   [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body" , Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
   public Body Body { get; set; }

   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "SOAP-ENV" , Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
   public string SOAPENV { get; set; }

   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsd" , Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
   public string Xsd { get; set; }

   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi" , Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
   public string Xsi { get; set; }

   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "SOAP-ENC" , Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
   public string SOAPENC { get; set; }

   [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "tns" , Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
   public string Tns { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You are missing he definition of the names space "SOAP-ENV".

Comment: actually not. i just cut that part out. ill edit it then^^

Comment: We need the lines with the namespace definition to help.  Without the namespace the xml is broken.

Comment: I edited it again and added the full xml i get and the classes i made for the deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

Best way of solving these issues is to create classes with sample data and serialize.  Then compare your serialized xml with original xml

```
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Envelope envelope = new Envelope() {
                Body = new Body() {
                    GetErrorCodesResponse = new GetErrorCodesResponse() {
                        Ns1 = "urn:LicenseManagement",
                        RETURN = new RETURN() {
                            Type = "tns:ReturnGetErrorCodes",
                            RC = new RC() {
                                Type = "xsd:int",
                                Text = "0"
                            },
                            DATA = new DATA() { 
                                Type = "SOAP-ENC:Array",
                                ArrayType = ":[55]",
                                Item = new Item[] {
                                    new Item() { Type = "xsd:string", Text = "OK"},
                                    new Item() { Type = "xsd:string", Text = "database unavailable"},
                                    new Item() { Type = "xsd:string", Text = "..."}
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));

            serializer.Serialize(writer, envelope);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I could solve my problem, in a very ugly, not elegant way.

StringReader reader = new StringReader(soapResult);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.ReadXml(reader);               

                var deserialized = XmlExtension.Deserialize<Envelope>(ds.GetXml());

Comment: That does not solve the issue.  You will just get a mess.  The DataSet ReadXml class when you get a XML that is more than three levels of child tags produces a fragmented dataset that is useless.  Once fragmented you can not put back together to get useful data.

Comment: I noticed. it worked well on the posted stuff, but when i tried doing it the same way with a "bigger" object i get an exception. I guess i will have to parse it on my own. losing my patience atm :D

Comment: There are lots of methods to parse xml.  I use all of them depending o the situation.  The Net XML library has issues with namespaces and doesn't always work.  I tried over the weekend to fix the classes and was able to serialize, but then wasn't able to de-serialize the results.  I'm not sure you can modify the existing xml.  You may want to modify the xml code that generates the file.  Otherwise, I agree that you may need to write you own custom parser using the Net Library Xml (or  XML Linq).  If you need additional help let me know.  My preference is to use XMl Linq.

Comment: sure, i will ask if i need further help and report if i can progress aswell. thanks a lot for trying mate.